# browser does not displays/executes ReactJS code

Tags: reactjs

I have written a simple hello world code in ReactJS, but when I run the code, the browser displays nothing. There is not any error displayed on console. Please tell what can be the problem. I am using WebStrom compiler, Chrome as browser and Windows 8.1 is the OS.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First React App</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render :function() {
        return(
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    <MyComponent/>, document.getElementById('content')
);
```

**project directory**

[image]

**browser display**

[image]

Comment: are you using webpack? let's have a look at that config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your `script.js` should be `script.jsx`?

It's a babel issue you're running into. Try replacing JSXTransformer with the official babel package:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>`